# KNIME - Execute a EXE program in a Workflow

Tags: knime

I have a workflow Knime, in the middle I must execute an external program to create an Excel file.

Exists some node that allows me to achieve this? I don't need to put any input or output, only execute the program and wait to generate the Excel file (I require to use this Excel for the next nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's could be used the External tool node. The node requires inputs and outputs... but, you can use a table creator node for input:

[image]

This create an empty table.

In the external tool node, you must include an Input file and Output file, depending on your request, this config could be meaningless but require to the Node works. 
[image]

In this case, the external app creates a text with the result of the execution, so, in the initial table (Table creator node), will be read the file and get the information into Knime.

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) two “External Tool” nodes which allow running executables on the command line:

- [External Tool](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.ext.exttool.ExtToolNodeFactory)
- [External Tool (Labs)](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.exttool.node.ExttoolNodeFactory)

In case that should not be enough, you can always go for a [Java Snippet](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.jsnippet.JavaSnippetNodeFactory) node. The [`java.lang.Runtime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class should be your entry point.

Comment: If you use a Java Snippet, beware of the std out and std error streams- there is a good description at https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html